# apache httpd name-based virtual host: use ip or domain name?

Tags: apache, dns, ip

In Apache web server, when using name-based virtual hosting you can use either the IP or the actual domain name in the `VirtualHost` directive.

(Name-based virtual hosting on Debian is enabled via `/etc/apache/ports.conf` through `NameVirtualHost <ip>:<port>` statement, where `<port>` has to be the same one as in a `Listen` directive.)

So, then this:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
    ...
```

or this:

```
<VirtualHost sub.domain.tld:80>
    ...
```

will equally work.

---

*What are the differences, and which approach should be preferred?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an IP address is preferred so that your config can be parsed even if DNS resolution fails.

You can use the ServerName directive to control which hostname the VirtualHost block applies to, without triggering a DNS resolution:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.tld
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/dns-caveats.html has more examples of good and bad practice.

Comment: Best and only valid answer which could be given. Kudos!